# Using graphene, when sending a graphql request with a client, how can I intercept + introspect post data?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, graphql, jwt, graphene-python

Using graphene, when sending an outbound graphql request with a client, how can I intercept + introspect query params and post data?

- This request is going from one backend service to another backend service
- Both queries an mutations are sent via POST

My use case is that I need to cryptographically sign a data payload(dict) but to do that I need graphene to go through the steps of converting the query int a GET or the mutation into a POST before I can grab the data from the query params or post body.

The input data needed to sign the request is the dict:

```
data = {
  "operationName": "blah",
  "variables": {},
  "query": "fancy graphql query here"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This request data:

- is available when calling client.execute
- is NOT fully available in the graphene middleware because we do not have access to the string value of the query in the resolve info (at least in the test client)

So the only place that one can access these inputs is right before client.execute is called or by making a custom version of the Client class, that implements an execute method, bake the signing in there, then call super().execute...